# Python requests .get() from multiple pages?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm learning how to webscrape with python and I'm wondering if it's possible to grab two pages with `requests.get()` so that I don't  have to make two separate calls and variables. For example:

```
r1 = requests.get("page1")
r2 = requests.get("page2")

pg1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.content, "html.parser")
pg2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content, "html.parser")
```

As you can see there's repeated code. Any way around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I like the **grequests** library for fetching multiple URLS at one time, instead of **requests**. Especially when dealing with alot of URLS or a single URL with many sub-pages.

```
import grequests  
urls = ['http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com', 'http://bing.com']  
unsent_request = (grequests.get(url) for url in urls)

results = grequests.map(unsent_request)
```

After this, `results` can be processed however you need. This works well with JSON data: `results[0]` = first URL data, `results[1]` = second URL data, etc..

more can be found [here](http://johndangerthornton.blogspot.com/2015/02/grequests-examples.html?m=1)

Answer (score 6):

You can use list assignment and comprehensions, although it isn't much shorter with only two pages.

```
pg1, pg2 = [ BeautifulSoup(requests.get(page).content, "html.parser")
                for page in ["page1","page2"] ]
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error, I'm not sure why. It says at the end I'm missing a ] or for?